# How to allow drops on JTable depending on source component?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I am looking for a way to allow drop to JTable only from particular components.
I have 4 `JTable` components (`DS1`, `DS2`, `DS3`, `DS4` (DT=DropSource)) to drag from and 2 `JTable` (`DT1`, `DT2` (DT=DropTarget)) that accept drops.

I want to allow drops in `DT1` from `DS1` and `DS2` and in `DT2` from `DS3` and `DS4`.

I have followed the [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) tutorial fully but could not find a way to get the drag source component.

So how to do it?

Comment: What did you try based on [Import Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/import.html)? It seems the [`TransferHandler.TransferSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.TransferSupport.html) can identify which component is the source, and the method reject a drop accordingly. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Comment: @AndrewThompson In [TransferHandler.TransferSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.TransferSupport.html) there is a method [getComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.TransferSupport.html#getComponent--) which returns the target component of this transfer But not the source component.